# Show a non-concurrent Map breaking under multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, java-8

I'm trying to demonstrate the problem of using an ordinary `Map` with multiple concurrent tasks. The following example (which compiles and runs) is intended to show the `Map` failing:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class BreakMap2 implements Runnable {
  private Map<Integer, Integer> map;
  public BreakMap2(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      int key = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10_000);
      if(map.containsKey(key)) {
        assert map.get(key) == key;
      }
      map.put(key, key);
    }
  }
}

public class MapBreaker2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 1000)
      .mapToObj(i -> new BreakMap2(map))
      .map(CompletableFuture::runAsync)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
      .forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
  }
}
```

This doesn't demonstrate the problem (it doesn't fail). How can I do this more effectively? Is there an approach that will fail quickly and reliably?

To clarify, I'm trying to show how it's unsafe to have multiple tasks writing to a `Map` that is not designed for concurrent use. I'm trying to create something that will show an incorrect write to a `Map` because of concurrent access.

**Edit:** I've simplified the example so now it just runs forever until you hit Control-C. What I'd like instead is for a failure to stop the program.

Comment: Looks like it's using a thread pool of size 1.

Comment: Your example seems overly complicated. What exactly would like to show?

Comment: What is the problem? You want to show that a non-concurrent map does not work under multiple threads? That is hardly more a problem than a car hitting  wall being damaged - it is well known and documented.

Comment: It doesn't shut down because you don't ever shut down the thread pool.

Comment: Made changes to address the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear which kind of “incorrect write” you are trying to provoke.

There is a broad variety of problems that can occur with concurrent updates of a data structure. One infamous problem with unsynchronized concurrent updates of `HashMap`, which indeed shows up in real applications, is `HashMap.get` being stuck in an infinite loop but, of course, your program which runs infinitely anyway wouldn’t be able to spot that.

The only thing you are testing is the value of a stored `Integer` with `assert map.get(key) == key;` This doesn’t test the object identity (otherwise it was doomed to fail due to the unspecified object identity of auto-boxed values), but rather the contained `int` value, which benefits from guarantees made for `final` fields, even if their owner object is published via a data race. So you are unable to see an uninitialized value here and it’s hard to imagine any scenario in which you could encounter a wrong value.

Since you are storing immutable objects whose values are immune to data races, only the structural updates to the `Map` itself may have an effect. But these are rare. You are filling the `Map` with random keys between `0` and `10000` in an infinite loop, so once all ten thousand distinct keys in that range are encountered, there will be no structural change anymore. Chances are good, that the first asynchronous task will reach that state even before the next task starts its work. Even if there is a short overlapping phase, the likelihood of encountering a data race right in that time window is low.

After that short time window, you are only replacing the values of existing mappings, as said, with objects immune to data races and, since they represent the same boxed values, the JVM may even optimize away the entire update.

---

If you want a program with a higher likelihood of failing, you may try the following. It performs a simple naive transfer from one `Map` to another, probing an entry and putting it into the target map if it exists. It looks simple and will indeed run smoothly with a thread count of one, but will fail badly in most environments when using any other thread count.

```
public class MapBreaker2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int threadCount = 2; // try varying that number
    Map<Integer, Integer> source = IntStream.range(0, 10_000)
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i, i->i));
    System.out.println("trying to copy "+source.size()+" mappings without synchonizing");
    Map<Integer, Integer> target = new HashMap<>();
    Callable<?> job=() -> {
        while(!source.isEmpty()) {
            int key = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10_000);
            Integer value=source.remove(key);
            if(value!=null)
                target.put(key, value);
        }
        return null;
    };
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    pool.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(threadCount, job));
    pool.shutdown();
    System.out.println(target.size());
    assert source.isEmpty();
    assert target.size()==10_000;
  }
}
```

But it should be emphasized that multi-threading without synchronization still is unpredictable, so it may run without a noticeable error in one or another test run…

Comment: Thank you ... this might well do the trick. I will investigate and get back to you.

Comment: I couldn't get the random copier to complete, but I was able to just perform multiple copies and get the effect:

    public void run() {
      for(int key : src.keySet())
        dest.put(key, src.get(key));
    }
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1677663: never completing is one of the possible outcome of the unsynchronized program. One possible reason is that there is a loss of updates to the source map’s size, so it’s never considered empty despite having no mappings anymore.